# Azure CLI Download error

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I am able to run the sample code apart from the 'azure storage blob download' statement.

No matter what I do I get the following error message:

error: ENOENT, open 'path to my local destination file'

any idea what the problem might be?

```
#!/bin/bash
# A simple Azure storage example

export AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT='my account'
export AZURE_STORAGE_ACCESS_KEY='my key'

export container_name='test4'
export blob_name='test.json'
export image_to_upload='/pathto my local file to uppload/test.json'
export destination_folder=~/path to my local folder for download/

echo "Creating the container..."
azure storage container create $container_name

echo "Uploading the image..."
azure storage blob upload $image_to_upload $container_name $blob_name

echo "Listing the blobs..."
azure storage blob list $container_name

echo "Downloading the image..."
azure storage blob download $container_name $blob_name $destination_folder

echo "Done"
```

Comment: Have you tried echoing the value of `destination_folder`?

Comment: yes it gives me the path on my local drive where I want the file to be downloaded

Comment: Do you have write permission to destination_folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I change the **destination_folder** to an explicit **file path** it works fine.

```
export destination_folder="/home/steven/Downloads/result.json"
```

It should be more appropriate to name it as *destination_file* rather than *destination_folder*.